# Writing file aborts with "failed to load image contents" from ImageIcon.writeObject()

Tags: java, file, serialization, icons

The thing is, I'm not knowingly using any icons. I use a chooser to select & name the output file, then:

```
public void savePictureFile() {
    FileOutputStream myFOS = null;
    ObjectOutputStream myOOS = null;
    File outputFile = chooseOutputFile();

    try {
        myFOS = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        myOOS = new ObjectOutputStream(myFOS);
        myOOS.writeObject(myDrawPanel.getPicture());
        myOOS.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I've read here all about the "failure to load icons", but as I said, I'm not trying to use any icons. If Java is attempting to use a default icon for my file, why can't it load it? 
The object I'm trying to serialize and write is an array of simple "Shape" objects.

Here's the latest full stack trace (I didn't omit anything from the last one except the "java.io.IOException"):

```
java.io.IOException: failed to load image contents
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.writeObject(ImageIcon.java:508)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1377)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1173)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
at Application.savePictureFile(Application.java:119)
```

And here's the stack trace trying to read the file back in:

```
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readInt(ObjectInputStream.java:2820)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readInt(ObjectInputStream.java:971)
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.readObject(ImageIcon.java:481)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1706)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1344)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
at Application.loadPictureFile(Application.java:157)
at ButtonPanel.actionPerformed(ButtonPanel.java:114)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: Post the full trace. Likely, the fault is in myDrawPanel.getPicture()

Comment: A thought: I haven't been using an extension on the file name. Is one required? I'm on a Mac currently.

Comment: Your edit misses the name of the primary cause (the part before *failed to load image contents*)

Comment: I tried a ".ser" filename extension. Same result.

Comment: The filename doesn't matter - What's the type of myDrawPanel ?

Comment: public class DrawPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener   and:       ArrayList<Shape> getPicture() {
  return Picture;
 }  (this ArrayList is home-grown, not the standard Java class)

Comment: I see no `getPicture` in the API of `JPanel`. If you added that API yourself, you must be sure that the returned type -whatever it is- is compatible with the Java serialization API

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My bad :=(

One of the classes I was using was written by somebody else and contained a totally random and unused reference to an image file. Taking that out fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For what I can see the exception was originated while trying to save the image "failed to load image contents", try to see if myDrawPanel.getPicture() doesn't return null.

But maybe the problem may be because of IO flush. Use try-with-resources and report results.

```java
File outputFile = chooseOutputFile();

try (ObjectOutputStream save = new ObjectOutputStream( new FileOutputStream( outputFile ) ) ) {
    save.writeObject( this );
}
catch ( IOException ex ) {
    //Exception handling goes here;
}
```

Comment: Ups, I got something wrong, I meant save.writeObject( myDrawPanel.getPicture() );

Comment: That looks like it might have worked (wrote 4KB file). But trying to read it back in gives another bunch of errors (see main post).

Comment: Oops. Spoke too soon (didn't notice there was no stack dump in your code). It gives the same error as before. I guess that would explain the EOF trying to read the file back.

Comment: Another think that came to my mind, is to use the class ImageIO. It is a class that encapsulates several static methods that write and read images.


If myDrawPanel.getPicture() is a BufferedImage, you can write it back to a file. BufferedImage implements RenderedImage, so it is possible to do so with the write() method.


http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html


I hope I could help.

Comment: myDrawPanel.getPicture() returns an ArrayList (home grown, not Java's) of simple objects (which contain no graphics). No images at all, anywhere that I know of.

Comment: I see, you want to create some sort of paint, and you are having trouble in recording it. I don't know exactly what to say, but have you implemented the Serializable Interface on your homebrew class?

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace points to an error in `ImageIcon.writeObject()`, so likely the problem is your icon is not loaded properly.

You can check the load status with [`ImageIcon.getImageLoadStatus()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#getImageLoadStatus%28%29): if it returns [`MediaTracker.ERRORED`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/MediaTracker.html#ERRORED) (the error code is `4`) it means you have a problem with the code that loads the image, and you won't be able to serliazie the JPanel without solving that other one issue before.

To spot the problem, look at your logs or at the exceptions you ignore in the relevant methods.

Comment: See, that's the thing: I don't have or refer to any icons anywhere. So "your icon" doesn't exist AFAIK. There is no code that "loads the image". I'm completely baffled.

Comment: @user3238181 please, try to look at anything that can draw an image, like a JLabel. There is certainly an ImageIcon stored somewhere